# Unable to modify this value in Debug

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can't set any value for input data, while debugging my procedure in Oracle SQL Developer.

When I try to change the value from NULL to any other I getting the following error. What is the problem? What does *"debugger process may not allow values to be modified"*, and how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try modifying any other values besides product_id? Typically product_id would nave a column definition that can't be changed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you cannot modify the value of a parameter.  I ran a quick test and was able to change the value of a variable, but got the same error message as you when I tried to modify a parameter.

There's no way to be sure though, Oracle debugging is a mess.  The DBMS_DEBUG documentation is wrong.  And there isn't any useful information for DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP, which is what SQL Developer uses.

You'll have to change the value before it is passed to the procedure, if possible.